# German DBpedia endpoint in HTTP Sparql Queries returns no result

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I am using the Jena Java framework for querying DBpedia end point using SPARQL, to get the type for all points of interest in German cities. I am facing no issue for places that have English DBpedia entries. But, when it comes to place names to be queried from the German DBpedia endpoint (http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Schloß_Nymphenburg), this query returns no result. This problem is also mentioned over here (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201110.mbox/%3C4E877C8A.4050705@apache.org%3E). Even after referring to this, I am unable to solve the problem. I don't know how to work with QueryEngineHTTP. I am adding two code snippets - one that works (first one - query for Allianz Arena : which has an English entry in DBpedia) and one that doesn't work (second one - for Schloß Nymphenburg, that has a German entry). 
This might be a very trivial issue, but I am unable to solve it. Any pointers to a solution would be very very helpful. 
Thanks a lot!
Code 1 - working :

```
String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
final ParameterizedSparqlString query = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
            "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>" +
            "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
            "PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>" +

            "SELECT * WHERE {" +
                "?s geo:lat ?lat ." +
                "?s geo:long ?long ." +
                "?s dcterms:subject ?sub}");
query.setIri("?s", "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Allianz_Arena");
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service, query.toString());
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);
```

Code 2 - not working :

```
String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
final ParameterizedSparqlString query = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
        "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>" +
        "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
        "PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>" +

        "SELECT * WHERE {" +
            "?s geo:lat ?lat ." +
            "?s geo:long ?long ." +
            "?s dcterms:subject ?sub}");

query.setIri("?s", "http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Schloß_Nymphenburg");
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service, query.toString());
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with jena at all. Trying:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Schloß_Nymphenburg> ?p ?o }
```

at http://dbpedia.org/sparql I get no results: [try it yourself](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fde.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSchlo%C3%9F_Nymphenburg%3E%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Schloss_Nymphenburg> ?p ?o }
```

by contrast returns something, even if it's just a bunch of [cross links](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fde.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSchloss_Nymphenburg%3E%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This one works for your query (`<http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Schloss_Nymphenburg> ?p ?o`). But, when I try to run `SELECT * WHERE { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Schloss_Nymphenburg> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?sub}` , it returns nothing.

Comment: If you look at my last link you'll see that it's nothing but owl:sameAs links, no subject or anything. I'm not sure what the problem is, but it's something about dbpedia not jena. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: That's right. Its the local german dataset of dbpedia, that is not returning the results. Thanks for the pointers!